# MagicalRecord several truncates, "then cannot find data for a temporary oid"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord, xctest

Before each test, I'm trying to wipe data and re-create fixtures. The app crashes every time it hits `MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait` however with `cannot find data for a temporary oid`

```
[A MR_truncateAll];
[B MR_truncateAll];
[C MR_truncateAll];
[[FixtureLoader instance] loadDataInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rather than truncate in tests, just use an in memory store and dump the store after every test. You'll not experience crashes, and it'll be far faster.

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];
}
```

Comment: Fair enough and a good idea that I'll definitely do, but what's causing the crashes? Is there something fundamental there that's wrong?

Comment: If your fixture loader is doing stuff in a background queue/thread then that might be causing the problem. The default context is generally for main thread access only.

Comment: I can't figure it out, but switching to in-memory fixes everything.